# Terminating a for loop in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Please explain this code and how the output came as 10?

```
class L1 {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<=9; i++); //termination
    {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

output

```
10
```

Comment: When will the loop terminate? (when i is 10)

Comment: Remove the semicolon: `for (i=0; i<=9; i++);`

Comment: **just one question...** *who wrote comment `//termination`???* ***that itself is the answer...***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) ; // at the moment for loop exit i=10
```

Since when `i=9` `i++` will increment `i` further.

I think you put `;` by mistake. Because of that `for` loop execute without having `for` loop body..

Try following. Now you can understand why you are getting this out put.

```
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        System.out.print(i);
    }
    System.out.println("\nprint i: "+i);
```

Out put:

```
   0123456789 // what for loop does
   print i: 10 // what i++ does
```

Answer (score 0):

i++ 
after the for loop is finished 
i will became 10

Comment: nope - it will not do `i++` after the loop - the last step after `i=9` will be `i++` setting `i` to 10 and then the condition `i<=9` for the loop will fail - this is technically still *in* the loop

Answer (score 0):

You have a ';' after your `for` line, this should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
for (i=0; i<=9; i++) {
  // do nothing
}
System.out.println(i);
```

You complete the loop doing nothing and *then* output the result.

If you want to output each value of `i`, do this:

```
for (i=0; i<=9; i++) {
  System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is like that,

```
    int i;
    //for (i=0; i<=9; i++); //termination
    for (i=0; i<=9;) {
        i = i + 1;
    }
    //now i is 10
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no semi-colon after the for loop. The way you have it written will iterate through the loop making i=10. Only then will it go on to print i.
The code should read:

```
    for (i=0; i<=9; i++)
        {
           System.out.println(i);
        }
```